# Duplicated uiview added programmatically

Tags: ios, uiview, addsubview, viewwillappear

I'm currently making a photo decoration app. The *holderView is the sticker that has been chosen by user. Whenever I try to load a photo from photo library or take a photo and then load back to this page, additional *holderView added programmatically, which is the sticker that I've previously chosen before taking a photo, duplicated sticker appears after that, which is not what I want it to be.

How should I write the code for not letting this happen?
Thanks a lot.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, _imagePicker.selectedImage.size.width, _imagePicker.selectedImage.size.height)];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
[imageView setImage:_imagePicker.selectedImage];
[holderView addSubview:imageView];
...
}
```

Comment: As I understanding, why you dont get the holderview when user chose this view, and then add the image view to this chosen holderview?

Comment: @huubby sorry can you further explain what you mean? Thanks

Comment: I mean, maybe you could keep the holderView that "you previously chosen before taking a photo", then when you need to show the image view (as your code showing, by adding the image view to a programmatically added holderview), you could just add the image view to the previous holderview you have kept

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be that your using the viewWillAppear method instead of the viewDidLoad. This will cause multiple "imageViews" because your adding a new one every time you hide then show the viewController it's presented in. what you want to do is move the creation of the imageView (if there really is  suppose to only be 1) to the viewDidLoad method and make that imageView accessible to the entire class, then in the viewWillApear simply change the image inside the imageView to the newly selected one.